# Swift - My collection view is not outputting an extra amount

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The count of chosenPlanArray.count is 5 here, and that is how many cells my collection view ends up having.

However, when i try an append values from the collection view to arrays, my collection view is iterating over itself an extra amount of times - in this example it gets to 9 iterations. Even though 'return chosenPlayArray.count' is 5. This is very random and ive been playing with my code all day trying to fix it. Has this ever happened to anybody ?

```
 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return chosenPlanArray.count

}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomPlanItCollectionViewCell



    cell.planImage.downloadedFrom(link: chosenPlanArray[indexPath.item].imageForPlan!)
    cell.planLbl.text = chosenPlanArray[indexPath.item].nameOfEvent
    cell.dateTimeLbl.text = chosenPlanArray[indexPath.item].eventStartsAt



    if cell.dateTimeLbl.text == nil {
            datesForFirebase = [""]
    } else {

        datesForFirebase.append(cell.dateTimeLbl.text!)


    }


    individualPlanNames.append(cell.planLbl.text!)




     imagesOfPlan.append(chosenPlanArray[indexPath.row].imageForPlan!)



    print(chosenPlanArray.count)

    print(imagesOfPlan.count)
    print(nameOfEventPlan.count)
    print(individualPlanNames.count)
    return cell
}
```

Here is my output for those print statements at the bottom. Notice how the first print statment is correct - the actual size of the collection view is 5, as you can tell by the numberOfitems in sec.. I find it weird how the other print statements start at 1, and then loop past the size of 'chosenPlanArray.count' - Is the issue the way i may be appending the values to my arrays? This is causing me to get the wrong number of values uploaded to my firebase. So i need to figure this tricky situation out. Thanks

```
5 // first print statement print(chosenPlanArray.count)
1 // second print statement print(imagesOfPlan.count)
1 // fourth  print(nameOfEventPlan.count)
1 // third print(individualPlanNames.count)

5
2
2
2

5
3
3
3

5
4
4
4

5
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
5
7
7
7
5
8
8
8
5
9
9
9
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that there is cell reusing , which means every scroll a call to `cellForItemAt` happens which means these  lines run again

```
individualPlanNames.append(cell.planLbl.text!)

imagesOfPlan.append(chosenPlanArray[indexPath.row].imageForPlan!)
```

and the size of their content increases

Comment: Oh! So that is why its adding more items. Is there any way for me to code around this?

Comment: now that you mention it, that does make complete sense. But i feel there has to be some solution around this. Since working with tables views and appending their values seems so common

Comment: If you need some filtering/processing make it when you receive the data not in cellForItemAt

Comment: Yes because i was sending the contents of these cells to firebase to store in the backend. I understand what you're saying. But for instance, how could i access - chosenPlanArray[indexPath.item].nameOfEvent - outside of cellForItem at? It will not let me call the dot notation on that class object unless i am inside of cellforRow and able to use the indexPath

Comment: calling webservices inside cellForItem is not a good practise if you are not carefully doing it , indexPath.row is an int from 0..<arr.count ,  you can loop through the items and send what you want outside of cellForItem